# Grand Child route not activating in angular

Tags: angular, routes, children, breadcrumbs

I have been trying to get a grand-child route to work in angular.  Read through the docs and found a bunch of answers here.

I am lazy loading a module with 3 components.  I am looking to achieve a hierarchy of
deployments > release > job.

deployments is a list view
release is the details view (has many jobs)
job is job details view

My App Routing:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/auth.guard';

export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'deployments',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'deployments',
    loadChildren: () => import('./deployment/deployment.module').then((m) => m.DeploymentModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
]
```

the deployment module routing:

```
    export const DeploymentRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DeploymentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ListDeploymentsComponent,

        data: { breadcrumb: { alias: 'deployments' } },
      },
      {
        path: ':release',
        component: DeploymentDetailsComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: ':jobId',
            component: JobDetailsComponent
          }
        ]
      },

    ],
  },
];
```

the list comes up fine.  I am able to get to my deployment details with this:

```
  public viewDeploymentDetails(deployment: Deployment) {
     this.router.navigate([`./${deployment.release}`], { relativeTo: this.route});
  }
```

I cannot get to the JobDetailsComponent from the DeploymentDetailsComponent

```
  public viewJobDetails(job: Job) {
     this.router.navigate([`./${job.id}`], { relativeTo: this.route});
 }
```

The breadcrumb I have in place is working correctly - but the component never loads?

[image]

UPDATED.

As pointed out in the comments - I did not have an angular router in the DeploymentDetails component.  Adding that - I now have the JobDetailsComponent rendering IN the deployment details component.

This is not the behavior I want.  I want three separate views (list, deployment details and job details) along the corresponding breadcrumb navigation.

I updated my routes to be flat (no children).

```
    export const DeploymentRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DeploymentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ListDeploymentsComponent,
        data: { breadcrumb: { alias: 'deployments' } },
      },
      {
        path: ':release',
        component: DeploymentDetailsComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':release/:jobId',
        component: JobDetailsComponent,
      }
    ],
  },
];
```

Now routing is working correctly - but the breadcrumb hierarchy is not.

[image]

Comment: Stupid question, but did you add a <router-outlet> to your `DeploymentDetailsComponent`?

Comment: Not a stupid question.  No I do not.  Now once I put that in - it resolves.  But this is not the behavior I want.  I now end up my JobDetailsComponent in the same view as the deployment details.

Comment: JDBennett I am not sure if your code provided is sufficient to answer why your breadcrumbs are not working properly. Can you add the expected + current result of breadcrumbs?